# Nginx reverse proxy for Nodejs server SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Tags: php, node.js, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, reverse-proxy

I'm using AWS Beanstalk to configure a multicontainer docker environment to both serve my PHP Docker Application parallel to my NodeJS Server, running on port 3000.

I have a running Express Server, listening on **port 3000**. I now want to be able to call my **NodeJS server** at `https://nodejs.my-domain.com:3000`. Nginx should now terminate the SSL connection and forward all traffix to my NodeJS Express server.

So far I can successfully reach my PHP Application both with and without *https*. I can also reach my NodeJS Application without SSL at `http://nodejs.my-domain.com:3000`. But as soon as I call it with **https** I get the Broser Error **SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG**.

Nginx config file looks like this:

```
log_format healthd '$msec"$uri"'
          '$status"$request_time"$upstream_response_time"'
          '$http_x_forwarded_for';

upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 256;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name nodejs.my-domain.com

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/nginx-selfsigned.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

    if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
        set $year $1;
        set $month $2;
        set $day $3;
        set $hour $4;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://nodejs;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    server_name localhost my-domain.com;
    root /var/www/public;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/nginx-selfsigned.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

    if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
        set $year $1;
        set $month $2;
        set $day $3;
        set $hour $4;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;

        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure which logs I have to pay attention to. Here is some output of various log files:

My `access.log` looks like this:

```
XX.X.XXX.X - - [18/Mar/2020:12:12:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36" "-"
XXX.XX.XX.XX - - [18/Mar/2020:12:27:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x" "-"
XX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [18/Mar/2020:12:54:16 +0000] "GET http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "AWS Security Scanner" "-"
XX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [18/Mar/2020:12:54:17 +0000] "GET http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/ HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "AWS Security Scanner" "-"
XX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [18/Mar/2020:12:54:17 +0000] "GET http://[::XXXX:XXXXX:XXXXX]/ HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "AWS Security Scanner" "-"
XX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [18/Mar/2020:12:54:17 +0000] "GET http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "AWS Security Scanner" "-"
XX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [18/Mar/2020:12:54:18 +0000] "GET http://[::XXXX:XXXXX:XXXXX]/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "AWS Security Scanner" "-"
XX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [18/Mar/2020:12:54:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "AWS Security Scanner" "-"
XX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [18/Mar/2020:12:54:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "AWS Security Scanner" "-"
XX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [18/Mar/2020:12:54:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "AWS Security Scanner" "-"
XX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [18/Mar/2020:12:54:19 +0000] "GET /latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "AWS Security Scanner" "-"
XX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [18/Mar/2020:12:54:19 +0000] "GET /latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "AWS Security Scanner" "-"
XX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [18/Mar/2020:12:54:20 +0000] "CONNECT X.XXX.XXX.XXX:80 HTTP/1.0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
XX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [18/Mar/2020:12:54:20 +0000] "CONNECT X.XXX.XXX.XXX:80 HTTP/1.0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
XX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [18/Mar/2020:12:54:20 +0000] "CONNECT X.XXX.XXX.XXX:80 HTTP/1.0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
XX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [18/Mar/2020:12:54:21 +0000] "CONNECT X.XXX.XXX.XXX:80 HTTP/1.0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
XX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [18/Mar/2020:12:54:21 +0000] "CONNECT X.XXX.XXX.XXX:80 HTTP/1.0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
XX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [18/Mar/2020:12:54:21 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xD2\x01\x00\x00\xCE\x03\x03\x11\xB9\xBB\xFD\xF6a\xD4\xAFQ\x1F\xC0\x99j\xFA#\xBCX\xF9A}'\xC9\x00\xF9\x98K0\x88\xBA\xEA\xC0\x09\x00\x00b\xC00\xC0,\xC0/\xC0+\x00\x9F\x00\x9E\xC02\xC0.\xC01\xC0-\x00\xA5\x00\xA1\x00\xA4\x00\xA0\xC0(\xC0$\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
XX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [18/Mar/2020:12:54:22 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xD2\x01\x00\x00\xCE\x03\x03\xD7\xED\xA5|\xF8u\xCA\x1C\xD17r\x8B1\xD5\x8F\xD07\x9C\xD7Y\x06h" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
XX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [18/Mar/2020:12:54:22 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xD2\x01\x00\x00\xCE\x03\x033':\xC6\xE6\x90\xA8M" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
XX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [18/Mar/2020:12:54:22 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xD2\x01\x00\x00\xCE\x03\x03" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
XX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [18/Mar/2020:12:54:23 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xD2\x01\x00\x00\xCE\x03\x03\xCB=\xFAi\xFA\x8F\x08\x1E\x98\xCEc\x19\x18\xDD\xA0\xAE\xC4{\x18E\xFD\xC2z\xC3\x97\xB5\x97\xFEW\xC0\xA6~\x00\x00b\xC00\xC0,\xC0/\xC0+\x00\x9F\x00\x9E\xC02\xC0.\xC01\xC0-\x00\xA5\x00\xA1\x00\xA4\x00\xA0\xC0(\xC0$\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
```

And in my `error.log` I found the following:

```
2020/03/18 11:01:40 [warn] 1#1: "ssl_stapling" ignored, issuer certificate not found for certificate "/etc/nginx/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt"
2020/03/18 11:01:40 [warn] 1#1: "ssl_stapling" ignored, issuer certificate not found for certificate "/etc/nginx/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt"
2020/03/18 11:14:44 [warn] 1#1: "ssl_stapling" ignored, issuer certificate not found for certificate "/etc/nginx/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt"
2020/03/18 11:14:44 [warn] 1#1: "ssl_stapling" ignored, issuer certificate not found for certificate "/etc/nginx/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt"
```

It also looks like there is something wrong with my healthd loggin config. There are many entries like this in my `healthd/deamon.log`:

```
# Logfile created on 2020-03-17 20:33:13 +0000 by logger.rb/47272
A, [2020-03-17T20:33:14.155980 #2972]   ANY -- : healthd daemon 1.0.3 initialized
W, [2020-03-17T20:33:14.249690 #2972]  WARN -- : log file "/var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.2020-03-17-20" does not exist
W, [2020-03-17T20:33:14.249690 #2972]  WARN -- : log file "/var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.2020-03-17-20" does not exist
[...]
A, [2020-03-17T20:34:03.782734 #4025]   ANY -- : healthd daemon 1.0.3 initialized
W, [2020-03-17T20:34:03.858118 #4025]  WARN -- : log file "/var/log/containers/nginx-proxy/healthd/application.log.2020-03-17-20" does not exist
W, [2020-03-17T20:34:03.858118 #4025]  WARN -- : log file "/var/log/containers/nginx-proxy/healthd/application.log.2020-03-17-20" does not exist
[...]
```

Comment: And what is in the nginx logs for those requests?

Comment: I added some info about my logging output above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. There were two things I was missing:

1. I am using a multi container docker environment with Nginx and Nodejs both running within their own container. In order for Nginx to be able to reach my Nodejs server I had to create a link between Nginx and Nodejs. But in my configuration file I configured the link within the Nodejs section instead of the Nginx section. I now added `"links": ["node"]` to the Nginx section within my **Dockerrun.aws.conf** which now looks like this:

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "nginx-proxy",
            "image": "MY_NGINX_IMAGE_ON_PRIVATE_REGISTRY",
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "hostPort": 80
                },
                {
                    "containerPort": 443,
                    "hostPort": 443
                }
            ],
            "links": ["node"]
            [...]
        },
        {
            "name": "node",
            "image": "MY_NODEJS_IMAGE_ON_PRIVATE_REGISTRY",
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 3000,
                    "hostPort": 3000
                }
            ]
        }
        [...]
    ]
    [...]
}
```

2. Further more instead of setting the upstream within my Nginx config to `127.0.0.1:3000` I had to do the upstream to my Nodejs docker container, which I named **node**: `server node:3000`. So my **/var/nginx/conf.d/default.conf** now looks like this:

```
[...]

upstream nodejs {
    server node:3000;
    keepalive 256;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name websockets.my-domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/websockets.my-domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/websockets.my-domain.com/privkey.pem;

    [...]

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade ${DOLLAR}http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP ${DOLLAR}remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For ${DOLLAR}proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host ${DOLLAR}http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://nodejs;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}

[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

please try to add TLS1.2 to the list of supported TLS protocols.

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
```

You can check the supported TLS version with openssl cli.

```
openssl s_client -connect my-domain.com:443 -tls1_2
```

if you get the certificate chain and the handshake the TLS-Version is supported.

I tested your configuration with a simple nodejs app on my CentOS7 VM:

```
upstream nodejs {

        server localhost:3000;
        keepalive 256;
}


server {

        listen 443 http2 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES1$
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

        location / {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://nodejs;
        }


}
```

Output of `curl -ivk https://localhost:443`

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 443 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate:
*   subject: O=Default Company Ltd,L=Default City,C=XX
*   start date: Mar 02 08:28:49 2020 GMT
*   expire date: Mar 02 08:28:49 2021 GMT
*   common name: (nil)
*   issuer: O=Default Company Ltd,L=Default City,C=XX
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.17.6
Server: nginx/1.17.6
< Date: Mon, 02 Mar 2020 08:55:02 GMT
Date: Mon, 02 Mar 2020 08:55:02 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 4
Content-Length: 4
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: Express
X-Powered-By: Express
< ETag: W/"4-5f2c/g6AOREdVLWI53srsMrUHDo"
ETag: W/"4-5f2c/g6AOREdVLWI53srsMrUHDo"

<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
done
```

No issues. I would suggest to start nginx in debug mode to see a more detailed log.

`systemctl stop nginx.service && systemctl start nginx-debug.service`

Please note: The debug level will create huge logfiles. Make sure not to use it extremly long.

add this to your config.
`error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;`

what version of NGINX are you using?

Comment: Same result. In an earlier version I also had `ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2` enabled. With same error.
The output of your command is:
`CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 C = DE, ST = City, O = My Company, CN = my-domain.com
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = DE, ST = City, O = My Company, CN = my-domain.com
verify return:1
`

Comment: Just for clarification: as because of your NGINX configuration your proxy server is listening on ports 80 and 443. NOT 3000. That means if you want reach your NodeJS application via your proxy, your address is something like https://my-domain.com. Port 3000 is your NodeJS app. Sorry - missed that in my first post. Can you try: curl -Iv https://my-domain.com. Whats the output?

Comment: ok, i did `curl -Iv https://my-domain.com:3000` and it returned `curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol`.

Comment: `* Rebuilt URL to: https://my-domain.com:3000/
*   Trying X.XXX.XXX.XXX...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to my-domain.com (X.XXX.XXX.XXX) port 3000 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
* Closing connection 0`

Comment: Not with port 3000. Port 3000 (as far as I can see) is your NodeJS app without the NGINX Proxy. Can you curl https://my-domain.com:443 and share the result?

Comment: Ah, ok. I see what you mean. 
Calling `https://my-domain:443` now says **502, Bad gateway**.
The result of curl is `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate`
Looks like the problem is my self signed certificate, right? But why doesn't the browser show that certificate warning that you can allow an untrusted certificate?
I'm planning to implement lets encrypt but first want to get everything up and running.

Comment: add -k option to curl `-k, --insecure      Allow connections to SSL sites without certs (H)`

Comment: I also don't understand, why calling port 3000 without TLS is serving me the correct website, when as you mentioned correctly it should only be listening on 80 and 443?

Comment: [...]
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
[...]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:

Comment: [...]
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x1657d10)
> HEAD / HTTP/2
> Host: my-domain.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
< HTTP/2 502
< server: nginx/1.16.1
< date: Wed, 18 Mar 2020 19:26:57 GMT
< content-type: text/html
< content-length: 157
<
* Connection #0 to host my-domain.com left intact

Comment: BTW: I changed the server_name from *my-domain.com* to the subdomain *nodejs.my-domain.com* so it does not collide with the server_name that the PHP app is served at.
In my above code I wrote my-domain.com to avoid confusion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209879/discussion-between-timo-stark-and-eric-xyz).